# Remove the one element on transformation if two same elements are found

Tags: xml, xslt

I transform multiple documents at once using XSLT. Those documents may have elements like
`<a:updated></a:updated>` or `<app:edited></app:edited>` and some of them have both `<a:updated></a:updated>` and `<app:edited></app:edited>`.

In this case some of the outputed document (besides it's standard elements like title, link, content) have two times a `<posted></posted>` element.

The question here is how do I remove the one `<posted></posted>` if `<app:edited>` and `<a:updated>` are found in the same `<entry></entry>`?

This is the heading of XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"  xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app">
```

This is the template

```
<xsl:template match="a:updated | app:edited">
  <posted>    
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
  </posted>
</xsl:template>
```

this is how I process it

```
$xproc = new XsltProcessor();
$xslt = new DomDocument;
$xslt->load('stylesheet.xslt');
$xproc->importStylesheet($xslt);
```

and this is basically the XML

```
<entry>
<id></id>
<title></title>
<content></content>
<link></link>
<a:updated></a:updated>
<app:edited></app:edited>
</entry>
```

Comment: +1 for the good question, but please, show us the XML. Generally how and whether at all a template is selected for execution, depends on the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction that selects this template. The solution, therefore is to apply templates only on one of the occurences of `a:updated` , `updated` , `app:edited`

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer depends on the source XML document, which you haven't shown.

Generally how and whether at all a template is selected for execution, depends on the `<xsl:apply-templates>` instruction that selects this template, so try something like this:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select=
  "(//*
     [self::a:updated 
     or 
      self::updated 
     or self::app:edited
     ]) 
      [1]
"/>
```

If possible, try to substitute the `//` pseudo-operator above with a more specific XPath expression, because the `//` is notorious for its inefficient nature.

**Update**: Now that the OP has posted an XML document, here is a more specific solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:a="a" xmlns:app="app" exclude-result-prefixes="a app"
 >
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=
      "(/*/*
         [self::a:updated
         or
          self::updated
         or self::app:edited
         ])
          [1]
    "/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="a:updated | app:edited">
      <posted>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*" />
      </posted>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (massaged to be made well-formed):

```
<entry xmlns:a="a" xmlns:app="app">
    <id></id>
    <title></title>
    <content></content>
    <link></link>
    <a:updated></a:updated>
    <app:edited></app:edited>
</entry>
```

**the wanted correct result** (`<posted>` occurs only once in the output) **is produced**:

```
<posted/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried it but gave me an error on XSLT Processor. However I managed to remove the 1 of the 3 elements, having now 2, as you can see in my updated question. I also posted the XML document.

Comment: @JohnQ: See my updated answer for a complete transformation -- just copy-paste-run it.